# Calling function's prototype from another which is called by clicking on html element

Tags: javascript, function, object

I have some functions like these:

```
function start () {
    document.getElementById('div1').onclick = clicked;
}
function clicked () {
    //here I want to use both the html element and the another_function
    alert('clicked div1: ' + this.innerHTML);
    another_function();
}
function another_function () {
    alert('I am another function.');
}
```

(in the `html` code I have only a div with `id="div1"`)

They work obviously fine, but now I want to "collect" them in one object function.
Now I have this:

```
function Obj () {
    document.getElementById('div2').onclick = this.clicked;
}
Obj.prototype.another_function = function () {
    alert("I am another function!");
}
Obj.prototype.clicked = function () {
    alert('clicked div2: ' + this.innerHTML);
    this.another_function();//doesn't work
    Obj.another_function();//this doesn't work, too
}
```

How can I call `another_function()`?
[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/kQ98x/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of `this` in the event handler is the element not the object, you can change it to reference the object instead with `bind()`

```
function Obj () {
    document.getElementById('div2').onclick = this.clicked.bind(this);
}
Obj.prototype.another_function = function () {
    alert("I am another function!\n" + 
          "I have just been called by the Obj function!");
}
Obj.prototype.clicked = function (e) {
    alert('clicked div2: ' + e.currentTarget.innerHTML);
    this.another_function();
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/kQ98x/3/)

Comment: When I click `two` the first `alert` alerts "clicked div2: undefined". Actually I have some divs and have to get both the clicked elements and the "obj" function in the `clicked` function.

Comment: @user3132718 - That's because you'll lose the reference to the element, so you'll have to get that from the event instead. Edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can call `another_function()` like this:

```
var two = new Obj();
two.another_function();
```

Comment: Yes, but I have to call it when the object is clicked, not when the window is loaded.